# When adding a .post() event listener to a Keystone model the isNew property always returns false

Tags: node.js, mongoose, keystonejs

I'm trying to hook into the first save event when creating a new document. Looks like this.

```
User.schema.post('save', function (doc) {

  console.log('The user is new? ', doc.isNew);

});
```

However even when I create a new user via the Keystone admin panel it returns false. Any idea why? Is the document getting touched again by Keystone in the background or something? How should I go about hooking into a new save?

Comment: In lieu of a better response from Jed, here's something that got it working.

Add a new property with the .pre() method which caches the value of isNew. Then check for that in a .post() hook. I guess isNew is never true in the post hook?

https://gist.github.com/aheckmann/2889412

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mongoose thing as far as I know. After you save the object, it is no longer new. Kinda makes sense once you think about it that way. The only workaround I've found is to put a custom attribute on the object during a pretty save handler, and removing it post save after using it to determine if the object had just been saved for the first time.

Comment: right. It looks like the isNew property is only true in the .pre() hook but always false in the .post() hook. The link I posted shows a technique for doing something like you describe.
Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yeah, saw your link. I was just trying to add in that it's working as designed; the designers simply had a different usage in mind for that attribute than what some of us would have liked.

Comment: It does make sense in a way. Really I suppose the object is actually *created* when you do `new Book()`and then using `.save()` is just persisting that objects. :p